# how to update real time data on tkinter label?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am showing encoder value on tkinter label at the same time I have a function which is updated in every 100ms.
So my problem is my encoder value is not updated in real time.
How to solve this issue ?
My code is here

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   import os
   import board
   import busio
   import pigpio
   import serial
   import tkinter as tk
   import rotary_encoder
   import Adafruit_MCP4725
   import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
   from PIL import ImageTk,Image

   s=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0',
                baudrate=9600,
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                timeout=0.05)


   dac=Adafruit_MCP4725.MCP4725(address=0x61)
 
   pi = pigpio.pi()
   path="/home/pi/logo.png"
   root=tk.Tk()
   img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
   panel=tk.Label(root,image=img)
   panel.pack()
   panel.place(x=930,y=1,height=50,width=70)
   root.title("Dynalec")
   root.iconphoto(False,img)
   root.geometry("1000x600")

   Dsel = 0
   cal_c= 0

   pos=0

   rpm = 0
   torq=0
   arr = [0,0,0,0,0]


   def callback(way):  # interrupt event sense on pin no 17,18

        global pos

        pos += way
        if pos >= 9999:
          pos=9999
        if pos <= 0:
          pos=0

        var.set(pos)
        dac.set_voltage(int(pos/2.441))

    def rpm_update():
    global rpm
    s.write(str.encode(i))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if s.inWaiting():
       rpm = s.readline(s.inWaiting())
       rpm = rpm.decode('utf-8',errors='ignore')
       rpm = rpm[5:-1]
    var2.set(rpm)
    
   def update():
       global rpm,torq

       try:
         rpm_update()
         var3.set(torq)

         pow = (float(torq)*float(avg_rpm))/9549
         pow=format(pow,'.2f')
         var4.set(pow)

       except ZeroDivisionError:
         pass

       root.after(100,update)

   #RPM Label
   L1=tk.Label(root,text="RPM/ %TC posn",fg="blue",font=("TimesNewroman",30,'bold'))
   L1.pack()
   L1.place(x=65,y=380)

   #RPM DEMAND value

   var=tk.StringVar()
   L2=tk.Label(root,fg="red",textvariable=var,font=("TimesNewroman",35))
   L2.pack()
   L2.place(x=65,y=431,height=50,width=280)

   #PRESENT RPM Label
   L5=tk.Label(root,text="RPM",fg="red",font=("TimesNewroman",45,'bold'))
   L5.pack()
   L5.place(x=220,y=55,height=70,width=240)
   #PRESENT RPM value
   var2=tk.StringVar()
   L6=tk.Label(root,fg="black",textvariable=var2,font=("TimesNewroman",70,'bold'))
   L6.pack()
   L6.place(x=220,y=116,height=90,width=240)
  
   """
   torque and power label for `var3` and `var4`.
   """
   
   

   decoder=rotary_encoder.decoder(pi, 17, 18, callback)
   root.update()
   root.mainloop()
```

I think due to root.update() this issue arises. But I need root.update() function also for this project.
So I need to update var.set() value when ever data will be there but var2.set() in every 100ms.
Do I need multithread??
So how can I ressolve this .

Comment: Can you please provide minimalistic working code? Why do you have `panel.pack()` then on the next line `panel.place(x=930,y=1,height=50,width=70)`?

Comment: `var3` and `var4` aren't defined.

Comment: @TheLizzard, `panel.pack` is used for little png size logo at the right side of tkinter window. and `panel.place()` for place it there. `var3 ` and `var4`for torque and power which will be calculated in `update()` function.

Comment: You should use only **one** of `grid`/`pack`/`place` per tkinter window/tkinter frame. You shouldn't use more than 1 geometry manager. Sometimes tkinter can freak out.

Comment: So as per you I need only `place`.

Comment: You know that when you call `rpm_update`, it sleeps for 0.1 sec so the tkinter label's data will update every 0.2 sec not the 0.1 sec you need.

Comment: But my real issue is coming after using `root.after()`.

Comment: Your code does not call `root.update()`.

Comment: @acw1668, I did call it in `root.after(100,update)`.

Comment: `root.update()` is not `root.after(100, update)`.  And I don't find `root.update()` in your code.

Comment: @acw1668, My main issue is value is updating late in `callback` function in `var.set(pos)`.

Comment: @acw1668, I updated code with `root.update()`.

Comment: You just call `root.update()` once before `root.mainloop()` and so it definitely not the cause.

Comment: @acw1668, So what should I do for `callback` function .So that value should update in real time . It is updating but with some delay.

Comment: Since `callback` is configured in the line `decoder=rotary_encoder.decoder(pi, 17, 18, callback)` and I have no idea of what `rotary_encoder` is, so I don't know how to help.

Comment: @acw1668, It's a encoder which value is incremented by 1000 in one rotation of clockwise direction. And without `update()` function ,`var.set(pos)` updating the `pos` value in real time.

Comment: So what does *"my encoder value is not updated in real time"* mean?  What is current behaviour and what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: You better use thread to run `update()` instead of using `.after()` because `sleep()` is called inside `update()`.

Comment: @acw1668, my encoder value is not updated in real time means ,the value is coming on display with a slight delay. Expected behaviour is It should update immediately on display